# 2D is to face as 3D is to?

Tags: geometry, terminology

Essentially, if a point is a zero-dimensional component of an object, a line is a one-dimensional component, and a face is a two-dimensional component, what is a three-dimensional component?

If there isn't a specific term for something like this, is there a generic term for it?

Comment: Generally, we stop inventing words and use the creative name of $k$-face or $k$-cell for a $k$-dimensional analogue of a face.

Comment: I think you need to give a lot more context for how you want this answer.
Depending if your an algebraic geomoter, or a theoretical physicsit, the answer can be much more complicated, or less rigirous!
What are you thinking about this in relation to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a bit surprised that you call the one-dimensional component a line, not an edge. To me, line suggests an infinitely extended component, while a face is usually bounded.

In 4d, a polytope would usually be described in terms of vertices, edges, faces and cells. See for example [the Wikipedia page on the 120-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/120-cell).

In higher dimensions, things are less clear, and e.g. in the context of a [CW complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex), *every* “component” is called a cell. So in that context, you'd have to qualify it, speaking expicitely of three-dimensional cells or simply 3-cells. This works nicely for any dimension.